# Jxls output excel file is not in same format as input template file

Tags: java, jxls

hi , 
 i am using jxls  for excel sheet generation , my problem is in o/p sheet i am getting extra rows , and some border styles also. for further reference i added two images here

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a foreach tag? That should prevent the extra rows being created:

```
<jx:forEach items="${collection_name}" var="collection_var">
${collection_var.PROPERTY_NAME}
</jx:forEach>
```